# android app not installed, the app with same package name already exists

Tags: android, installation, apk, release

I had a release version of an app installed on the device. I made a new release version where I changed versionCode and versionName. When I try to install new apk on a device it is telling me that the app with the same package name already exists. It does not tell me anything else (e.g. conflicting signature etc.). Thus I cannot install a new version without uninstalling the old one that is not what I want. What could be wrong?

https://ibb.co/hpiZp5

https://ibb.co/gctOhQ

Comment: How did you install it? If you're installing it from command line, don't forget to add `-r`

Comment: I sent signed apk by email and everyone has been installing this way

Comment: Please make sure you are using the same key to sign both APKs, even if the previous APK was signed with a debug-key from another SDK, the keys will definitely be different.

Comment: but both versions are release versions

Comment: Hi, Ana I am stuck in the exact same problem. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It happened same with me. Check in the guest account of your phone, need to uninstall from there as well.

Comment: but I don't want to uninstall the old version and lose the data.

Comment: Since, you installing from new version apk, the older app doesn't know it's an update.